# Where to download HttpServlet.java v1.2?

Tags: servlets, javax

We have a old system that use  HttpServlet v1.2, where can I download source for debug in eclipse? I googled obky found v2.0 or v3.0...
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(version 1.2 : 46.0, ...) indicates that this class file was compiled with java 1.2.

Java 1.2 was specified for both servlet-api 2.2 and 2.3.

As Tomcat has been the reference implementation of these specifications forever, it is possible to rummage through their archive and find (for example) [Tomcat 3.3](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/), which was the RI for the 2.2 specification.

A list of distributions can be found at http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-3/. If you dig through the binary distributions there you will find a `servlet.jar` which might match your needs.

If this turns out to be too old (indicated by missing methods in the Java classes it provides) then you will need to search forwards in the Tomcat archives to find the release that implements the Servlet 2.3 specification instead.

(It looks like http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-4/ and related contains the Servlet 2.3 spec jars)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I downloaded servlet-api 2.5 source.

Comment: Did you really want 2.5? Typically you would just get the jar file rather than the source itself

Comment: I need to debug in eclipse and check source, I already have jar file.